# Javascript - truncating text

Tags: javascript

I develop an app that showing people's profile. The profile can be in English or Chinese character. At one point I have to truncate the text to feed into the page. This is what I do now for temporary measure:

```
if(descriptiontext.match(/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/)){///<-- check if it is chinese character
        truncateddescription = descriptiontext.slice(0, 80);
    }else{
        truncateddescription = descriptiontext.replace(/\s+/g," ").split(/(?=\s)/gi).slice(0, 20).join('');
    }

truncateddescription = truncateddescription + '...';
```

This works if the input is either Chinese or English, what if they put half Chinese or half English, I am not sure what will happen.

Is there a better way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Can you also explain what you are trying to achieve? like why `slice(0, 80)` for Chinese but `slice(0,20)` for English?

Comment: Also if its about showing limited characters and showing `...` at the end, try CSS ellipsis instead. That will allow you to have entire text and still show desired result

Comment: @Rajesh chinese character do not have space, so you just count to 80 character in my case and truncate it. For English however, first I have to replace(space) and split them by the space, then I count words, in my case, 20 words. So far it works fine. But I am anticipating they will mix the English and Chinese, in a sense, English with Chinese translation. So I am trying to see how to make it work.

Comment: So considering the fact that Chinese do not have `spaces`, you can just do `string.trim().split(" ");` If length is greater than `1` its either mix or English. If not, its Chinese and you can check length of string